# is there a a way to parse a string and use querySelector with corvid wix?

Tags: jsdom, velo

I fetched a html page as a string and would like to retrieve the text between  tags and get a value from a json key.
In javascript, this works :
For instance, if the string is :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
  <head>
    <script>
      window.changeTargetingData = {
                "petition":{
                      "id":"19197290",
                       "signatureCount":{"total":323030,"displayed":323030}
                           }
                  };
 </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

This gives me what I want in javascript :

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(textResponse, 'text/html');
const script = doc.querySelector('script');
const objJSON = script.textContent.match(/window.changeTargetingData = ([^]+);/)[1];
const obj = JSON.parse(objJSON);
console.log(obj.petition.signatureCount.total);
```

but I didn't find DOMParser or any DOM requests in corvid. Does anything exists to get a value from a html page ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you just need to change what is written on the doc.
It's :

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
const domm = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
console.log(domm.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent);
```

and now it works....